# Specify the type of a vector with a string

Tags: c++, types, vector

How do you specify a type with a string? 
I mean:

```
string s = "int";
Vector<s> vec;
```

And I want vec to be `vector<int>`.
Is this possible?

I want to make a class where the user can type in a string and a vector with that type will be created.

Comment: You need some sort of variant data type.

Answer (score 5):

Not possible in C++, atleast not the way you want.

Templates are a *compile time* concept, while user input is a *runtime* concept. Completely different, not mixable.

To make that work, you need a dynamically typed language, which C++ is not. It's statically typed.

Comment: Ok, but I want to do this because i want to implement a multidimensional vector, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579207/hypercube-c-multidimensional-vectros . Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

> Is this possible?

This is not possible in C++. If using boost is an option, consider creating a vector of [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) objects instead: this way, your statically-typed `vector` would be prepared to accept elements of different types.